# Images use & location, on new wordpress theme

Tags: theme-development, images, css

I am trying to migrate a website i hand coded myself and i have to make it a wordpress theme now. I'm having trouble using the different images i've used throughout the index.html, they can't be loaded -getting a 404 error on the dev tools console-.

My question is, **where should i put my images and how can I succesfully retrieve them in my new theme**? do i put them all in an img/ folder? or do they have to be uploaded through media?

the images range from img tags, to embedded svg objects, 
examples:

```
<img src="img/Logos-crear.png">

<object>
    <embed src="img/icons/twitter.svg">
</object>
```

and background images using css:

```
.header .header-img {
    background: url("../img/main.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code and rename index.html to index.php.

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/Logos-crear.png">
<object>
<embed src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/icons/twitter.svg">
```

that should work fine.no need to change in css code.